# TFS255231 - VMM server name can't be changed

Tags: tfs

We need change the configured SCVMM server to another SCVMM server on TFS console.
But it throws the following exception:

[image]

Also we cannot delete the groups and library shares for each team project collection from TFS console.

Could anyone give some clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, we fixed the issue by follow the [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518919.aspx).

In order to retain the lab settings, we use the following commands:

```
Tfsconfig.exe lab /settings /scvmmservername:NewSCVMMNameOrIP /force
```

TfsConfig.exe in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools

Log:

> Logging sent to file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configurati
>   on\Logs\CFG_SET_URL_0807_105542.log
>   Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server Configuration Tool
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Command: lab Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server
>   Configuration Tool Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Do you want to overwrite the existing settings with these new values ?
>   (Yes/No) Yes 
>   You may have lab resources associated with the current
>   SCVMM server. Are you sur e you want to overwrite the current SCVMM
>   server name ? (Yes/No) Yes The requested changes were successfully
>   applied.